# Does a joint distribution have a unique decomposition into a marginal and conditional distribution?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I believe this is true.

The argument is that if we fix $p_{XY}$, then the marginal $p_X$ is immediately fixed. So for any $q_X\neq p_X$, there exists no conditional probability distribution $Q_{Y|X}$ such that $q_X Q_{Y|X} = p_{XY}$. This implies that every joint distribution has a unique decomposition into a marginal and conditional distributions.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: You showed that the marginal distribution is unique. However, the conditional distributions $(Y\mid X=x)$ as a function of $x$ is not uniquely determined. To see this, you can consider the special case where $(X,Y)$ are jointly continuous with the density $f_{X,Y}$. Then $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_X(x)$ is only well-defined when $f_X(x)>0$, and you have ultimate freedom for the choice of $f_{Y\mid X=x}$ for $f_X(x)=0$ without affecting the joint distribution.

Comment: @SangchulLee good point. So the only case where the conditional distribution is not unique is when the marginal distribution has zeroes (discrete case), yes?

Comment: The general situation is more complicated than that. The statement in full-generality is as follows: Let $(X, Y)$ be a random vector, and let $\mu(\cdot)=\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot)$ denote the marginal distribution of $X$. Then the conditional distribution of $Y$, given that $X=x$, namely the transition kernel $$K(\cdot \mid x)=\mathbf{P}(Y\in\cdot\mid X=x),$$ is determined $\mu$-almost everywhere (and only in that sense). In particular, modifying $x\mapsto K(\cdot\mid x)$ on a $\mu$-null set does not affect the joint distribution.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

Let $(\Omega_X, \mathcal{F}_X)$ and $(\Omega_Y, \mathcal{F}_Y)$ be measurable spaces, and let $X:\Omega_X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Y: \Omega_Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be random variables. Let $P_X$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega_X, \mathcal{F}_X)$. The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the extension of a pre-measure on the semialgebra $\{A_X \times A_Y \subset \Omega_X \times \Omega_Y: A_X \in \mathcal{F}_X,\ A_Y \in \mathcal{F}_Y \}$ given by
$$P((X,Y) \in (A_X \times A_Y)) = \int_{A_X} K(\omega_X, A_Y) P_X(\mathrm{d}\omega_X),$$
where $K:\Omega_X \times \mathcal{F}_Y \rightarrow [0,1]$ is a *transition function.* In other words, $K$ satisfies

(1) for each $\omega_X \in \Omega_X,$ $K(\omega_X, \cdot)$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega_Y, \mathcal{F}_Y)$; and

(2) for each $A_Y \in \mathcal{F}_Y$, $K(\cdot, A_Y)$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_X$, where we assume $[0,1]$ has the Borel $\sigma-$algebra generated from the standard Euclidean topology.

By Caratheodory's Extension theorem, this pre-measure extends uniquely to a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}_X \times \mathcal{F}_Y.$

The "conditional distribution" to which you refer is $K$. It then follows that $K(\cdot, A_Y)$ can take arbitrary values on sets to which  $P_X$ assigns measure $0$.

Source: A Probability Path by Sidney Resnick.

Comment: So, I guess your answer is essentially a rephrasing of the fact that the conditional distribution $(Y\mid X=x)$ is determined only $\mathbf{P}(X\in\mathrm{d}x)$-almost surely.

Comment: Yes. I included the background because the original poster is probably not familiar.